# Trying to read and write data using gspread; ended with APIErrors: Quota exceeded for quota metric

Tags: gspread

gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 429, 'message': "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Read requests' and limit 'Read requests per minute per user' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:81537768804'.", 'status': 'RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED', 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'consumer': 'projects/81537768804', 'quota_metric': 'sheets.googleapis.com/read_requests', 'quota_limit': 'ReadRequestsPerMinutePerUser', 'service': 'sheets.googleapis.com'}}]}

Comment: This is expected, you can read about it here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.